# Using df.query on MultiIndex gives UndefinedVariableError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have two dataframes

```
df
Out[162]: 
          colA  colB
L0 L1 L2            
A1 B1 C1     1     2
      C2     3     4
   B2 C1     5     6
      C2     7     8
A2 B3 C1     9    10
      C2    11    12
   B4 C1    13    14
      C2    15    16

df1
Out[166]: 
               rate
from to            
CHF  CHF   1.000000
     MXN  19.673256
     ZAR   0.000000
     XAU   0.000775
     THB  32.961405
```

When I did

```
df.query('L0=="A1" & L2=="C1"')
Out[167]: 
          colA  colB
L0 L1 L2            
A1 B1 C1     1     2
   B2 C1     5     6
```

Which give me back the expected out put .

Then I want to apply the same function in df1

```
df1.query('ilevel_0=="CHF" & ilevel_1=="MXN"')
```

and

```
df1.query('from=="CHF" & to=="MXN"')
```

Both failed

What happened here ?

---

Data Input :

```
#df
{'colA': {('A1', 'B1', 'C1'): 1,
  ('A1', 'B1', 'C2'): 3,
  ('A1', 'B2', 'C1'): 5,
  ('A1', 'B2', 'C2'): 7,
  ('A2', 'B3', 'C1'): 9,
  ('A2', 'B3', 'C2'): 11,
  ('A2', 'B4', 'C1'): 13,
  ('A2', 'B4', 'C2'): 15},
 'colB': {('A1', 'B1', 'C1'): 2,
  ('A1', 'B1', 'C2'): 4,
  ('A1', 'B2', 'C1'): 6,
  ('A1', 'B2', 'C2'): 8,
  ('A2', 'B3', 'C1'): 10,
  ('A2', 'B3', 'C2'): 12,
  ('A2', 'B4', 'C1'): 14,
  ('A2', 'B4', 'C2'): 16}}


#df1
{'rate': {('CHF', 'CHF'): 1.0,
('CHF', 'MXN'): 19.673256,
  ('CHF', 'THB'): 32.961405,
  ('CHF', 'XAU'): 0.000775,
  ('CHF', 'ZAR'): 0.0}}
```

Comment: So, `from` is a reserved keyword in python, so using it in `query` doesn't work.

Comment: df1.query('ilevel_0=="CHF" & ilevel_1=="MXN"') this works on my computer.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yeah , i notice that but why ilevel_0 still not working ...

Comment: @Tai error code on my side `pandas.core.computation.ops.UndefinedVariableError: name 'ilevel_0' is not defined`

Comment: `ilevel_0` is the name given to the axis when it has no name. If the axis already has a name, then you need to use that name in query. On the other hand, if you do `df1.rename_axis([None, None])` and _then_ call query, you get your answer.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ that is a good explanation :-) thank you !

Comment: Think that is why it works because now I don't have index names on the df.

Comment: @Tai yes, I Think I forget that too :-)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ nope .....I received couple of downvote recent day ...have no idea about it ...

Comment: Thanks again man.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ is someone do this on purpose , sign~... T_T

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider -

```
df1

               rate
from to            
CHF  CHF   1.000000
     MXN  19.673256
     THB  32.961405
     XAU   0.000775
     ZAR   0.000000
```

First, the reason for `df1.query('ilevel_0=="CHF" & ilevel_1=="MXN"')` not working, is because your index already *has* a name. `ilevel_*` is the name assigned, when the index does not yet have a name. So, this command gives you an `UndefinedVariableError`.

Next, the reason for `df1.query('from=="CHF" & to=="MXN"')` not working, is that `from` is a keyword in python, and when pandas `eval`s the expression, `from == ...` is considered invalid syntax. One workaround would be -

```
df1.rename_axis(['frm', 'to']).query("frm == 'CHF' and to == 'MXN'")


              rate
frm to            
CHF MXN  19.673256
```

Another would be getting rid of the axis names -

```
df1.rename_axis([None, None]).query("ilevel_0 == 'CHF' and ilevel_1 == 'MXN'") 

              rate
CHF MXN  19.673256
```

Keep in mind that `query` suffers from a host of limitations, mostly revolving around restrictions with variable names.

Comment: The multi-index  related api, contain too many tricks , Hope they can fix it in the future :-)

Comment: @Wen Yep, would hope that they could make the API a little cleaner, or get rid of it.

Comment: For me , I even want to `reset_index` rather than working with multiple index , it's pain ...

Comment: Brilliant answer!